# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stream 39 sent too many headers EOS: false on running gRPC server with 500 clients

Tags: grpc, grpc-java, protoc

I am working on a bi-directional streaming gRPC POC where I have a gRPC client,
which is spawning 500 threads to simulate 500 clients, each doing the rpc call parallelly every second.
On the gRPC server side,
When client make the first connect, I save the responseStreamObserver and link it with the client's ID,
so the server can use the StreamObserver when needs to push message to client.

When running this setup I see below errors :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stream 39 sent too many headers EOS: false
and io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception$StreamException: Stream closed before write could take place
```

When I run a single instance/thread in the client, I see no errors. Seems to me that this is caused due to thread synchronization issue. Can anyone please help in resolving this? I'm blocked. :(

Following is my server implementation:

```
    public StreamObserver<DataRequest> processBidirectionalStream(StreamObserver<DataResponse> responseObserver) {
    return new StreamObserver<DataRequest>() {
                        private String clientId;
                        private int requestCount = 0;
                        private boolean isFirstRequest = true;
                        @Override
                        public void onNext(DataRequest request) {
                            clientId=request.getClientId();
                            if(isFirstRequest){
                                //Store the first StreamObserver for this client
                                clientObservers.put(clientId, responseObserver);
                                isFirstRequest = false;
                            }
                            //Increment request count for the client
                            requestCount = clientRequestCounts.getOrDefault(clientId, 0);
                            requestCount++;
                            clientRequestCounts.put(clientId, requestCount);
                            //Push the message to kafka topic for processing
                            processChunk(request.getName());
                            //Send a response back to the client after 5 requests
                            if(clientRequestCounts.get(clientId)%5==0){
                                DataResponse response = DataResponse.newBuilder()
                                        .setMessage("****Notification sent****")
                                        .build();
                                clientObservers.get(clientId).onNext(response);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                            System.err.println("Encountered error in bidirectional stream: " + throwable);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {
                            System.out.println("Bidirectional streaming RPC completed");
                            clientObservers.get(clientId).onCompleted();
                        }
                    };
    }
```

Tried running 500 clients (as separate threads here) which are doing parallel rpc calls to the gRPC server every second.
Expected gRPC server to handle the requests and send appropriate response whenever needed to each client (on ad-hoc basis, not on every request.)
Seeing errors in server as below when this set-up is run:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stream 39 sent too many headers EOS: false
and 
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception$StreamException: Stream closed before write could take place
```

Following is the stack trace when run with 10 clients for testing purposes:

```
Encountered error in bidirectional stream: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: client cancelled
2024-02-26 10:56:39.588 ERROR 21736 --- [ault-executor-8] io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor     : Exception while executing runnable io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl$1StreamCreated@78959964

io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: call already cancelled. Use ServerCallStreamObserver.setOnCancelHandler() to disable this exception
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:524) ~[grpc-api-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$ServerCallStreamObserverImpl.onNext(ServerCalls.java:366) ~[grpc-stub-1.42.1.jar:1.42.1]
    at com.philips.fp.service.GrpcServer.sendMessageToClient(GrpcServer.java:120) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.philips.fp.service.GrpcServer.processBidirectionalStream(GrpcServer.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.philips.fp.grpc.DataProcessorGrpc$MethodHandlers.invoke(DataProcessorGrpc.java:204) ~[classes/:na]
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$StreamingServerCallHandler.startCall(ServerCalls.java:235) ~[grpc-stub-1.42.1.jar:1.42.1]
    at net.devh.boot.grpc.server.metric.MetricCollectingServerInterceptor.interceptCall(MetricCollectingServerInterceptor.java:138) ~[grpc-server-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.9.0.RELEASE.jar:2.9.0.RELEASE]
    at io.grpc.ServerInterceptors$InterceptCallHandler.startCall(ServerInterceptors.java:244) ~[grpc-api-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
    at io.grpc.Contexts.interceptCall(Contexts.java:52) ~[grpc-api-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
    at net.devh.boot.grpc.server.scope.GrpcRequestScope.interceptCall(GrpcRequestScope.java:75) ~[grpc-server-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.9.0.RELEASE.jar:2.9.0.RELEASE]
    at io.grpc.ServerInterceptors$InterceptCallHandler.startCall(ServerInterceptors.java:244) ~[grpc-api-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl.startWrappedCall(ServerImpl.java:651) ~[grpc-core-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl.startCall(ServerImpl.java:629) ~[grpc-core-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl.access$1900(ServerImpl.java:416) ~[grpc-core-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl$1StreamCreated.runInternal(ServerImpl.java:556) ~[grpc-core-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl$1StreamCreated.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:531) ~[grpc-core-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) ~[grpc-core-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) ~[grpc-core-1.30.0.jar:1.30.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: The error indicates that a connection was cancelled while a write was blocked on flow control.  Is your server configured to handle 500 simultaneous requests?  If not, it may be sending goAways which if they happened to come while a request was queued would produce this.

Comment: "Stream closed before write could take place" may be okay and not much of a problem. I'd focus on the "Stream 39 sent too many headers EOS: false".  The stack trace is needed for that.

Comment: @LarrySafran In that case, should I service each request in a separate thread in the gRPC server? (500 threads in my case. Using ExecuterService).
Unary RPC works fine with 500 clients. I am seeing this issue only when it's a bidirectional implementation and when using a stored responseObserver from client for sending notification/acknowledgement on ad-hoc basis.

Comment: @EricAnderson
Updated the question with stacktrace.

Comment: @EricAnderson
I was able to find that the gRPC server is attempting to send a message to a client, but the client has already cancelled the RPC call. Most of the threads are failing with this.
Basically, ((ServerCallStreamObserver) responseObserver).isCancelled() is being set to true. Hence, when server tries to respond, it fails.

Any idea how to go about resolving this?

Comment: @VaibhavHalgeri, that is an explanation for the "Stream closed before write could take place". Those are just logged; everything should be behaving fine from them. The only _problem_  I see is "Stream 39 sent too many headers." That doesn't seem like it should be happening.